# change drawable of animated clip with code

Tags: android, drawable, clip

Alright, it is troubling me for quite some time now, so here it goes:

**main.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/some_id
    android:src="@drawable/some_clip"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"/>
```

**some_clip.xml**

```
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:clipOrientation="vertical"
  android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable_that_i_want_to_change"
  android:gravity="bottom"/>
```

I'm trying to access `some_clip.xml` and be able to change the drawable by code, is this possible. Any help or guidelines are appreciated!

Comment: how do you want to change your Drawable?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I want to manipulate the drawable inside a simple if statement. I am not sure though that I'm answering your question :/

Comment: ok, what do you want to change?

Comment: I want to change this drawable of some_clip.xml : android:drawable="@drawable/my_drawable_that_i_want_to_change" to a newly set drawable of my choice.

Comment: Drawable d = new ClipDrawable(Drawable drawable, int gravity, int orientation); iv.setImageDrawable(d);

Comment: I cant believe it works! I managed to tie it also with my ugly code. Thank you soo much! please answer the question its the least i can do to thank you! :D